# Can we fit a count data model that can predict zeros on the basis of data that does not contain the zeros?

Tags: poisson-distribution, missing-data, count-data, intercept

Suppose that I have a set of count data where I have complete data for observations where at least one event happened (i.e. there are cases with zero observations but they do not appear in my data). I do know how many zeros there are but not any other information about them. For the cases I do have observations for there is an upper bound of 10 counts.

If I am willing to assume that the zeros follow the same process as the cases I have observations for, is there some way for me to fit a poisson model or similar to the observed cases and then make predictions for a new case that would also allow me to predict the probability that it would be a zero. e.g. by adjusting the intercept or something similar.

Comment: Look into a technique called a zero-truncated poisson regression. I don't know if it will allow you to make predictions about future potential 0s, but it is the model you would use to make inferences about your data.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it seems like you could just add the zeros back into your data, unless covariates are involved that are unavailable for zeros. If there are such covariates, I don't exactly know what to do in general (depends a lot on the exact scenario). Pretending these observations do not exist is not an option. Secondly, knowing that some counts are >=10 is a case off right - censoring (i.e. the likelihood contribution is $P (Y_i\geq 10)$.

A Poisson or perhaps better negative binomial model will automatically predict some zeros no matter its parameters (the probability of a zero may just be arbitrarily close to zero). If there are substantially more zeroes than these models predict then zero inflated models are an option.

Comment: All covariates are missing for the zeros.

Comment: That makes it pretty tough to do anything much, unless you can make some assumptions about the covariates for the cases with zero events. It might be possible to e.g. do a joint model for the covariates and the counts. Or perhaps you know something about the marginal distribution of covariates?!